# How to restructure the line with proper alignment in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to get the Software Information from Red Hat. As far as I have tried,

```
rpm -qi <softwarename>
```

provides the enough information [image: Software Information]

from the above information, I do require **Name, Version, Release, Vendor, Build Date, & Install Date**.

I could able to get the **Name Version Release & Install Date** by using the following command.(here I have grepped only name and version for simplicity)

```
rpm -qi perl-Git | grep -E '^Name      :|^Version     :' | awk -F 'Relocations:|Vendor:' '{print $1}'
```

I have no clue to get the Right side of the Information, since I could not able to find a split string between two fields.
Any suggestions ??

Comment: I think you are better off using rpm's -q (query) formatting to get the stuff you want outputted the way you want it. From there you can attack it with `awk` if you need to. [read more here about how to do that](http://rpm.org/user_doc/query_format.html) and [the manpage for all the types you can include](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm)

Comment: I agree with with formatting, but you can always use, e.g. `rpm -qi pkgname | grep '^Name\|^Version' | awk '{print $3}'` The equivalent using *queryformat* would be `rpm -q --queryformat "%{NAME}\n%{VERSION}\n" pkgname`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Awesome... Thanks a lot you saved my entire day...

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Jack provided a good answer for you. There is a lot you can do with `--queryformat` and a C-style `printf` formatting statement. @JNevill provided excellent links to the exact web references which are a bit easier on the eye than `man rpm` (though that works just as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--queryformat`

```
$ rpm -q --queryformat "%{NAME}\n%{VERSION}\n%{RELEASE}\n%{VENDOR}\n%{BUILDTIME}\n%{INSTALLTIME}\n" perl-Git
perl-Git
2.8.0
1.WANdisco.308
(none)
1459260423
1493311622
```

Then you can print it how you like, and parse it how you like.

Comment: Didn't notice, since the package name over-rides that option.

Comment: Yes, not a big deal, it just looks kinda *wonky* (highly technical term) with the package name following the string.

Comment: Fixed it.  Just for you.  <3 :D